# Kafka Streams: group by subsequent identical keys and time windows

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a **scenario** that could be described like this. Imagine there are 2 types of keys coming in: A and B (in reality, there are more). Let's say (different) records enter the KStream in following order:

```
A1 
A2 
A3 
B1 
B2 
A4 
A5
```

In my scenario, the order of operations is important and I cannot process `A4` before `B1` or `B2`. However, I'd like to be able to process the records as batches. The way I see it, the best option to batch this input looks like this, i.e. reduce the input to 3 "batch" objects:

```
[A1 A2 A3]  
[B1 B2]  
[A4 A5]
```

I could then apply a function to each batch using `forEach`.

**Complexity:** The application is time-sensitive and it's not acceptable to keep aggregating records until its type changes (and a new batch is required). In other words, if the time between `A1` and `A2` is more than some time `t`, a batch with `A1` should be generated when `t` expires. The output then look like this (assuming all other records entered the stream in close succession):

```
[A1]
[A2 A3]  
[B1 B2]  
[A4 A5]
```

---

**Question:** How do I obtain a KStream with such batch objects while also taking time windows into account?

---

**My initial solution** (which probably doesn't work) for the final scenario (with delay between A1 and A2):

```
[KStream] incoming data with 2 possible keys: A or B, e.g. [ (A, A1), (A, A2), ...]
  |
  |   selectKey(key + something to separate A1, A2, A3 from A4 and A5 because B1 and B2 are inbetween) 
  v
[KStream] e.g. [ (A-group1, A1), (A-group1, A2), ... , (B-group2, B1), ..., (A-group3, A4) ]
  |
  |   groupBy(key)    // So either A-group1, B-group2 or A-group3
  v
[KGroupedStream] 3 different streams
  |
  |   WindowedBy  e.g. 1 second
  v
[TimeWindowedKStream] (still 3 different streams I guess?)
  |
  |   reduce()  --> Make "batch" objects out of window, e.g. a batch object is [A2, A3]
  v
[KTable]  (no idea how this look like, I guess one row per time window?)
  |
  |   toStream()
  v
[KStream] 1 stream with 4 entries like I described in the final scenario above
```

Could this work? Is this efficient? What are your thoughts?

Comment: Your requirements are very specific and thus and I don't think that the DSL will work for you. I would recommend to use the Processor API.

Comment: Doing this with the DSL itself is indeed really hard. I was able to fulfill my requirements using a simplified scenario only taking the time constraint into consideration. However, due to the fact that Kafka Streams only triggers processors when a new record is accepted to the partition (as explained in https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-take-on-watermarks-and-triggers/), the timing constraints were often not met. e.g., when at some point in time, 2 records enter at the same time, the batch containing these 2 is only released when a new record enters (potentially hours later).

Comment: You can use wall-clock time punctuation in the Processor API to address this.